# ggplot2 loads in R but not in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

ggplot2 will load in R but NOT in RStudio on a new installation of R 3.4.1 and RStudio 1.0.153 on Windows 10 Pro (1703) 64-bit. The ggplot2 is version 2.2.1

In RStudio when I try:

```
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library")
```

I get the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:

.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'grid', details:

call: fun(libname, pkgname)

 error: object 'L_initGrid' not found
In addition: Warning messages:

1: failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for layoutRegion to layoutRegion since layoutRegion is already defined in the ‘grid’ namespace 

2: failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for xsplinePoints to xsplinePoints since xsplinePoints is already defined in the ‘grid’ namespace
```

P.S. I installed ggplot2 with:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
```

ggplot2 loads just fine in R

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it "loads just fine in R"? You mean the default R GUI? Compare the `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()` between your R and Rstudio. Do you really need to explicitly set the `lib.loc=`? Do you have some unusual configuration?

Comment: Yes. ggplot2 loads in the default R GUI (and not in RStudio both with and without `lib.loc=`). `.libPaths()` are the same for both deafult R GUI and RStudio. `sessionInfo` is the same for both too, except in RStudio it also gives me the warning "_failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for parseLatex to parseLatex since parseLatex is already defined in the ‘tools’ namespace_"

Comment: Complete uninstall and reinstall solved it